# How to display data from table where data is filled in sql server 2005 

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hello 
       i want to show data from table where i have to show only that data that column contain some value . i don't want to show null value column of the employee . here i am try to show only that value that employee field in his details not blank column in his data . can any one help me that how to write query in sql server 2005 .

Comment: Not enough info - **what** does your table look like (columns, their datatype, what's stored??) and **what** and **how** do you want to access your SQL Server data?? PHP? C#? T-SQL? PowerShell??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I'm not sure what your table looks like, but something like this should get you started:

```
select e.details
from dbo.employee e
where e.details is not null 
and e.details <> ''
```

Comment: but there is no of columns into table . how to check for all column that it is null of blank

Comment: @lucky jain - you have to have a table schema, right? I guess I don't understand the question...

Comment: hello brett my problem is that i have one employee table. i want to show the data from that table but there is condition i want to show only that data that employee contain value not a blank column .

Comment: @lucky jain - you need to select a consistent number of columns as a result, so you can do this by either combining various values into one column, or selecting empty/null values with your query

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is:

```
select COL_NANE from TAB_NAME WHERE CONDITION
```

if your CONDITION is COL_NAME is not empty/not blank this mean as Brett wrote:

`COL_NAME <> ''` or `COL_NAME is not NULL`